# WPF Accessing StoryBoard from another Style

Tags: wpf, storyboard, styles

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="GridStoryBoard" >
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="-358" />
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="2" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource GridStoryBoard}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

How I can access story board from one style in another? Receiving "Cannot find resource named 'GridStoryBoard'. Resource names are case sensitive."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You need to define the `Storyboard` as a separate resource:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Key="GridStoryBoard" >
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="-358" />
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="2" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource GridStoryBoard}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

It can then be accessed by any `Style`. If you define it as a resource of a particular `Style`, it can only be used by that particular `Style`. That's why you would define it there in the first place. So if you want to be able to use it in several styles, it makes no sense to define it inside `<Style.Resources>`.

Comment: How to target particular grid then, or use it in GridStyle?

Comment: Exactly like you did before? It's still just a resource.

Comment: Get what? You asked how to be able to access the Storyboard from another style and I answered that question with a sample. Please ask a new question if you have another issue or clarify what you want.

Comment: Storyboard in your answer targets nothing, in my example It was used in Grid. How to target StoryBoard that has been from Grid to Grid?

Comment: In your example it's just a resource that is not used anywhere, isn't it? What are you using the Storyboard for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163729/discussion-between-spirosi-and-mm8).